# JavaScript moneyFormat() function

Tags: javascript, beginner, functional-programming

Using JSX syntax I wrote a function that takes either a float or an integer as a parameter and returns a formatted string. I'd like any feedback for refactoring the code.

```js
const moneyFormat = (float) => {
  let answer = [];
  let firstHalf;
  let secondHalf;

  // check if whole number
  if (float % 1 === 0) {
    float = Math.trunc(float);
    firstHalf = float.toString();
    secondHalf = '.00';
  } else {
    float = float.toFixed(2);
    const splitNumArr = float.split('.');
    firstHalf = splitNumArr[0];
    secondHalf = '.' + splitNumArr[1];
  }

  let everyThree = 0;
  // push chars into answer array
  for (let i = firstHalf.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    answer.push(firstHalf[i]);
    everyThree += 1;
    // insert space for every three chars 
    if (everyThree % 3 === 0) {
      answer.push(' ');
    }
  }
  // reverse array and add secondHalf
  answer = answer.reverse().join('') + secondHalf;
  return answer;
}

console.log(moneyFormat(2310000.159897)); // '2 310 000.16'
console.log(moneyFormat(1600)); // '1 600.00'
```

Comment: I assume you (like me) are a beginner and are making your own code for the things you learn while doing so :) If you were doing this for a production server you would, of course, Google to find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-dollars-currency-string-in-javascript. Just chucking this link here for anyone coming from a search engine looking for a money formatter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Bad variable names. `dollars` and `cents` would be more appropriate that `firsthalf` and `secondhalf`... I mean, c'mon, these variables don't represent "halfs" of anything. `float` isn't very descriptive either. Perhaps `rawvalue` would be better, and maybe `result_buffer` would be better than `answer`.
- The entire code for whole numbers is unnecessary. When you run `toFixed()` on a whole number it becomes a float (string) anyway.
- Rather than creating a new variable and arbitrarily swapping between `let` and `const`, why not just reassign `float` (or in my version, `raw_value`). You won't need it anymore after that anyway.
- You might wanna consider casting it to a float in case a string is passed to the function, in which case your `toFixed` would fail.
- It doesn't make a hue difference whether you declare your variables at the top or as needed when you're working on a small function, but be consistent. And if you do declare them all at the top, I would suggest doing it in a single statement for a small performance boost. In this case, I would personally just declare them as you go to keep the function concise.
- When you're doing a backwards loop like that you don't need all three statements in the for loop. You could just do `for (let i = firstHalf.length; i--;)`. That said, looping backwards and then reversing (or looping at all for that matter) makes for smelly code. You can just use a little regular expression to chunk the chars up: `/.{1,3}/g`
- Don't reassign a variable just to return it, just return it. It's less work for the computer that way.

```js
const moneyFormat = (raw_value) => {
  raw_value = parseFloat(raw_value).toFixed(2).split('.');
  let dollars = raw_value[0],
    cents = '.' + raw_value[1],
    format_buffer = dollars
      .split('').reverse().join('') // reverse it
      .match(/.{1,3}/g) // chunk it
      .map(c=>c.split('').reverse().join(''))
      .reverse(); // reverse it again
  return format_buffer.join(' ') + cents;
}

console.log(moneyFormat(2310000.159897)); // '2 310 000.16'
console.log(moneyFormat(1600)); // '1 600.00'
console.log(moneyFormat("1600"));
console.log(moneyFormat("234123.2134123"));
```

Comment: Uh, when I run your code snippet your numbers are reversed in each group of three, e.g. `moneyFormat(1600)` -> `1 006.00`

Comment: @DarkMatterMatt - lolwut.. it's 2am why am i answering things on stackexchange... fixed it but it's a little more complicated than i would have liked.. hopefully someone else has a better idea

Comment: It might be worth defining `const reverse = str => str.split('').reverse().join('')`